# mPDF creates blank page after TOC when using different orientation

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF file via `mPDF` where the sheets have the following orientation:

```
___________
| Page 1   |
|          |
| Portrait |
|          |
___________
___________
| Page 2   |
|  TOC     |
| Portrait |
|          |
___________
__________________
| Page 3          |
| Landscape       |
|                 |
__________________
___________
| Page 4   |
|          |
| Portrait |
|          |
___________
```

However, changing the orientation of page 3 makes mPDF create a blank page between page 2 (TOC) and page 3.

The PDF is created in HTML and then processed to mPDF. The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page page-landscape { size: landscape; }
        @page page-portrait { size: portrait; }

        div.landscape {
            page: page-landscape;
        }
        div.portrait {
            page: page-portrait;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>First page - displayed Portrait. The second page should be the TOC (portrait) and the 3rd should be on landscape</div>
    </div>

    <tocpagebreak />

    <div class="landscape">
       <bookmark content="TOC entry" level="0"/>
        <tocentry content="TOC entry" level="0"/>
        <p>TOC entry - Shouldn\'t have a empty page before</p>
    </div>

    <div class="portrait">
        another page
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

I've tried a number of things to make this work, without success. I'll list some of them:

- Using `toc-selector="page-portrait"` on the `<tocpagebreak>` tag
- Using `toc-orientation="P"` on the `<tocpagebreak>` tag
- Adding a `<pagebreak orientation="L" />` after the `<tocpagebreak>`
- Using `class="landscape"` in the `div` after the TOC, using the `@page` selector, as shown in this example
- Setting the variable [`autoPageBreak`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/autopagebreak.html) to `false` on mPDF's constructor
- Wrapping the pages in `div` and messing around with the position of `<pagebreak>`

I was using mPDF v6.0 and now I'm updating to mPDF v8.0.1. This issue occurs on all versions (6, 7 and 8). While on version 6 I used a hack by adding `$mpdf->DeletePages(2);` after `$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);` but this has two major problems:

1. This method is undocumented and seems buggy
2. With this, the page number doesn't match the correct pages, so I can't add page number on the footer

Is there any way to accomplish this without a blank page? Or a viable workaround?

Comment: Check out with [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).
Ps. I cannot comment so I am posting is as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to make this work. The key is to add `class="landscape"` (or the name you set on CSS) to the container of `<tocpagebreak />` and not the actual page you want to display on landscape.

So the HTML should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
         @page page-landscape { size: landscape; }
         @page page-portrait { size: portrait; }

        div.landscape { page: page-landscape; }
        div.portrait { page: page-portrait; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="portrait">
        <div>First page - displayed Portrait. The second page should be the TOC (portrait) and the 3rd should be on landscape</div>
    </div>

    <div class="landscape">
        <tocpagebreak />
   </div>

    <div>
     <bookmark content="TOC entry consolidacao" level="0"/>
        <tocentry content="TOC entry consolidacao" level="0"/>
        <p>TOC entry - Shouldn't have a empty page before</p>
    </div>

    <div class="portrait">
        <bookmark content="2nd page" level="0"/>
        <tocentry content="2nd page" level="0"/>
        <p>2nd page</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the `<div class="landscape">` wrapping the `<tocpagebreak />`. This actually doesn't change the orientation of the TOC but rather the next page - I imagine it has something to do with the internals of mPDF.
Then, when you want to change the orientation to portrait, just add the `class="portrait"` on the page you want it to be applied (as seen on "2nd page").

Other things to note are:

1. If you have a wrapper for all the content with a padding, it seems to create a blank page at the top or before the TOC (for whatever reason). I had a `<div class="page-content">` as the child element of `<body>` and the class had a `padding: 15px;` which made mPDF create a new page.
2. If you're using stylesheets, I advice you to drop them while testing. This sample works as is but if you try it when you have external stylesheets it may not work as expected. When this happens it means some style is forcing mPDF to create a blank page (this was how I found out about 1.). Besides, I was using Bootstrap's `row` and `col-xx` classes and remove them all.
3. Use `<pagebreak />` only to create new pages but keeping the orientation. Alternatively use `style="page-break-before: always;"`. This is important because while fiddling around you may find yourself creating a new page with `<pagebreak />` while just trying to change the orientation, thus giving you a new blank page.
4. Finally, if you're using `$mpdf->SetFooter()` or `$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter()` (or the corresponding Header methods), once you use the `@page` selector, the header / footer won't be displayed on the page. You need to set a named header/footer and specify it via CSS on the `@page` selector. See [example 5 on the docs](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-4.html#example-5---page) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the code in the question and updated it to generate pdf without empty page after TOC in pdf.

It is given [here](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/tocpagebreak.html) that TOCpagebreak will always start at an odd page number. Also, there is an [issue with mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/227) where it adds a blank page after TOC page.

I have divided the html code in two parts and deleted the blank page after TOC to get the final pdf.

The code in php is:

```
require_once __dir__.'/vendor/autoload.php';


$html = '<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page page-landscape { size: landscape; }
        @page page-portrait { size: portrait; page-break-inside:avoid; }

        div.landscape {
            page: page-landscape;
        }
        div.portrait {
            page: page-portrait;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>First page - displayed Portrait. The second page should be the TOC (portrait) and the 3rd should be on landscape</div>
    </div>

<tocpagebreak />';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$page = $mpdf->page;


$html2= '<div class="portrait" style="page-break:avoid !important;">
       <bookmark content="TOC entry" level="0"/>
        <tocentry content="TOC entry" level="0"/>
        <p>TOC entry - Shouldn\'t have a empty page before</p>
    </div>

    <div class="landscape">
        another page
    </div>
</body>
</html>';


$mpdf->WriteHTML($html2);
$mpdf->DeletePages($page);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Hi @wpexpert. Thanks for your contribution. As I said in the question, `DeletePages` is not an optimal solution since the TOC paging and the footer's `{PAGENO}` and `{nbpg}` get screwed up. Not sure what's the advantage of dividing the HTML in two though.
I did manage to sort out the issue (see my answer) without `DeletePages` and without any blank page, after a lot of trial/error.
Thanks.